# simple flutter app takes too much time to load

Tags: flutter, performance, animation, webview

i am making a simple webview app, which takes too much time to load,
in release mode or in actual device, I tried trimming code but it's not working, in devtools I can see errors like "Vsync process callback, animator begin frame" also shade compilation jank detected,

my code
main.dart

```
import 'package:auction_wind/homepage.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'notificationservice/local_notification_service.dart';

Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification?.title);
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.requestPermission();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Made by Shriramgupta8141@gmail.com',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

homepage.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

import 'bottomBar.dart';
import 'demo.dart';
import 'notificationservice/local_notification_service.dart';

bool netState = true;

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  late WebViewController _controller = WebViewController();

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controllerCompleter =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  Future CheckConnection() async {
    final connectionStatus = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      setState(() {
        netState = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        netState = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    CheckConnection();

    // 1. This method call when app in terminated state and you get a notification
    // when you click on notification app open from terminated state and you can get notification data in this method

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(
      (message) {
        print("FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage");
        if (message != null) {
          print("New Notification");
          if (message.data['_id'] != null) {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Demo(
                  id: message.data['_id'],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );

// 2. This method only call when App in forground it mean app must be opened
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
      (message) {
        print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen");
        if (message.notification != null) {
          print(message.notification!.title);
          print(message.notification!.body);
          print("message.data11 ${message.data}");
          LocalNotificationService.createanddisplaynotification(message);
        }
      },
    );

    // 3. This method only call when App in background and not terminated(not closed)
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
      (message) {
        print("FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen");
        if (message.notification != null) {
          print(message.notification!.title);
          print(message.notification!.body);
          print("message.data22 ${message.data['_id']}");
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _goBack(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: bottomBar(),
        body: netState
            ? Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                child: WebViewWidget(
                    controller: _controller
                      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
                      ..setNavigationDelegate(
                        NavigationDelegate(
                          onPageFinished: (String url) {
                            _controller.runJavaScript(
                                "document.getElementsByClassName('logo me-lg-4')[0].remove();" +
                                    "document.getElementsByClassName('cookies-card bg--default text-center cookies--dark radius--10px')[0].remove();");
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://auctionwind.com'))),
              )
            : const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No internet Conncetion',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _goBack(BuildContext context) async {
    if (await _controller.canGoBack()) {
      _controller.goBack();
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Do you want to exit'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('No'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      SystemNavigator.pop();
                    },
                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              ));
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }
}
```

error screenshot
[image: devtools]

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter run --profile` which shows actual performance of the app. You can get more info [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/performance#:%7E:text=Use%20a%20profile%20build%20of%20your%20application%20to%20analyze%20performance.)

Comment: tried this, still same issue